# How to use SVG image in ImageView

Tags: android, svg, androidsvg

Good Day, I have a `SVG` image. How can I add it to `ImageView` background?

I tried to use [this library](https://github.com/BigBadaboom/androidsvg). But I have problem:

```
01-25 12:19:02.669 27719-27719/com.dvor.androidapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #70: Error inflating class com.caverock.androidsvg.SVGImageView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
    at com.dvor.mobileapp.checkout.ShoppingCart.onCreateView(ShoppingCart.java:411)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:953)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1136)
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1499)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:456)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
  at com.dvor.mobileapp.checkout.ShoppingCart.onCreateView(ShoppingCart.java:411) 
  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786) 
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:953) 
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1136) 
 at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739) 
 at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1499) 
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:456) 
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862) 
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.caverock.androidsvg.R$styleable
  at com.caverock.androidsvg.SVGImageView.init(SVGImageView.java:80)
  at com.caverock.androidsvg.SVGImageView.<init>(SVGImageView.java:66)
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
  at com.dvor.mobileapp.checkout.ShoppingCart.onCreateView(ShoppingCart.java:411) 
  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786) 
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:953) 
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1136) 
 at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739) 
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1499) 
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:456) 
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862) 
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**What I did ?**

Firstly, I added `dependency` to `gradle`:

```
compile 'com.caverock:androidsvg:1.2.1'
```

Secondly, I changed `ImageView` to `com.caverock.androidsvg.SVGImageView`

```xml
<com.caverock.androidsvg.SVGImageView
        android:id="@+id/recentlyViewed_imgView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        svgimageview:svg="clock.svg"
        />
```

After that I added `xmls:svgimageview` to root layout:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:svgimageview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/rowItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#272727"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

This `clock.svg` is in the `assets` folder.

Comment: "But I have problem" -- when asking questions on Stack Overflow, please provide the entire stack trace.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html#svg

Answer (score 169, accepted):

In new Android Studio there is possibility to import SVG to XML file, so you don't need to use external library.

In drawable right click -> New -> Vector Asset -> Local SVG file.

[image]

Then You use it normally as other drawables:

```
android:src="@drawable/btn_image"
```

Comment: In case of using Support Library, add `app:srcCompat="@drawable/btn_image"`

Comment: Support for advanced SVG features seems to be pretty weak, though.

Comment: It's a nice idea but doesn't answers the question. Android's vector drawable format is *terrible* for all but the simplest images. SVGs from common graphic design tools don't convert well and Studio/Android doesn't even do a very good job of respecting the image's size.

Comment: You're right you should use XML drawables where you can, but if you are remotely downloading SVG images on the fly, this is what the library would be beneficial for. Because using webviews sucks

Comment: This has to be done at compile time. What if I have an SVG image that I download from a server at runtime?

Comment: And with some GRADIENTS very bad

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid color value url(#pattern0)

Answer (score 3):

On newer devices that have hardware rendering turned on by default, you need to explicitly turn on software rendering.

```
imgView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

**OR** add this tag in your xml

```
android:layerType="software"
```

Answer (score 3):

To properly use the `svgimageview:svg` attribute, the app needs to know it's definition.  Unfortunately, there is only a JAR version of the library at the moment, and (unlike with AARs) the needed definition does not get merged properly when the app is built.

Try copying the `attrs.xml` file from the library source

https://github.com/BigBadaboom/androidsvg/blob/master/androidsvg/src/main/res/values/attrs.xml

into your `res/values` folder.

I believe that should fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Right Click on Drawable -> New -> Vector Asset -> select Local file (SVG, PSD)
select Path where your image

example
/Users/yourpcname/Desktop/taka.svg

[image]

[image]

its save drawable as a xml file
Then you can use into your imageview.

Answer (score 2):

Though SVG is XML-based Vector image, Imageview can render only XML(Vector Drawables). Thus, We need to convert SVG to XML format. We can do it using Android Vector Asset Studio.

This may be helpful to convert SVG, PSD to XML
https://medium.com/@iamitgupta1994/converting-svg-psd-to-xml-vector-drawable-using-android-vector-asset-studio-8e8ec23d5405

Answer (score 0):

Locate where your svg image is.Rightclick drawable folder on res,
choose new>>>>Vector Asset>>>Local SVG>>>> and save it as xml